# expl3's regex_replace_all has a problem with German ß, why?

Tags: expl3, german, l3regex

**EDIT:** Solution for *this* problem below.

I'm trying to have an in-text direct replacement of entire words, but it seems using `regex_replace_all` does not work properly as it does not find a word ending with ß.

**I do not want to use "s for ß *in the text to be replaced itself*, although that works!**

As a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\replaceText}[1]{%
    \f_replace_text:n { #1 }
}

\tl_new:N \l_replace_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l_replace_a_tl
\tl_new:N \l_replace_b_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \f_replace_text:n #1 {%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_text_tl { #1 }
    \f_replace:
    \tl_use:N \l_replace_text_tl
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \f_replace: {%
%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_a_tl { Grieß }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_b_tl { Mehl }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \b\u{l_replace_a_tl}\b } { \u{l_replace_b_tl} } \l_replace_text_tl
%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_a_tl { Grießmenge }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_b_tl { Mehlmenge }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \b\u{l_replace_a_tl}\b } { \u{l_replace_b_tl} } \l_replace_text_tl
%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_a_tl { some }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_b_tl { more }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \b\u{l_replace_a_tl}\b } { \u{l_replace_b_tl} } \l_replace_text_tl
%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \noindent Writing some text.
    \replaceText{Replacing some text.}
    \replaceText{Forgetting to replace Grieß.}
    \replaceText{But not forgetting to replace Grießmenge.}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

> Writing some text. Replacing more text. Forgetting to replace **Grieß**. But not forgetting to replace Mehlmenge.

However, I would have expected:

> Writing some text. Replacing more text. Forgetting to replace **Mehl**. But not forgetting to replace Mehlmenge.

Why does it do that and how can I prevent it doing so? I've tried some ways of escaping the character in the regex but I haven't been able to get it to work.

**EDIT:**
*In this case*, the following additions make it work:
Replacing all instances of ß with its ligature "s before using the other regex commands which are then using the "s ligature only (inside the search, not necessarily in the replacement) and then changing them back at the end:

```
\tl_new:N \l_replace_utf_tl
\tl_new:N \l_replace_ligature_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \f_replace_text:n #1 {%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_text_tl { #1 }
    
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_utf_tl { ß }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_ligature_tl { "s }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \u{l_replace_utf_tl} } { \u{l_replace_ligature_tl} } \l_replace_text_tl
    
    \f_replace:
    
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \u{l_replace_ligature_tl} } { \u{l_replace_utf_tl} } \l_replace_text_tl
    
    \tl_use:N \l_replace_text_tl
}
```

Comment: well the problem is the \b. With `Grieß.` it doesn't match as both the previous ß and the following period are of class W. With Grießmenge it works as m is of class w.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that for a match there has to be a word boundary `\b`, that means a change from the `\w`-class to `\W` or the other way round.

But `l3regex` doesn't currently support full unicode. The class `\w` contains only ascii `[A-Za-z0-9\_]`. That means that the `ß` (or more precisely the two bytes building the ß)  belongs to `\W` and so does the period and so `Grieß.` doesn't match.

Comment: For ref for the OP: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/920 is where we are tracking the need for Unicode support

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept the answer and comment a solution for this particular problem once I've found one.

Comment: I'm guessing since it's text, searching for space, comma, full stop semicolon, colon, exclamation mark, question mark, slash, parentheses, braces, quotes and dashes as word delimiters will suffice as those are almost all the possibilities for usual text, but it's far from general...